# Git - List files recursively by branch/tag name

Tags: git, git-ls-files, git-ls-tree

I want to see file trees without cloning all remote files. Is it possible using git commands?

git version `2.21.0`

My current commands are below:

```
- mkdir my-repo && cd my-repo
- git init
- git remote add origin https://remote-repo-url 
- git fetch
- git checkout origin/master -- '*.html'
```

How can I get only .html files  as fast as I can? My repo is really huge. I need only .html files.

Answer (score 1):

For the existing `my-repo`, you could try `sparse checkout`.

```
echo '*.html' > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git -c core.sparsecheckout=true checkout origin/master
```

Only html files and their parent folders will be left and the others will be hidden.

If you need to do it from scratch, use `git fetch --depth 1` to minimize the cost of time and network.

If it's a routine task from scratch, you can make a mirror clone in advance to save time and space for future tasks.

```
git clone --mirror https://remote-repo-url -- /path/to/mirror
```

And for the routine task,

```
git clone https://remote-repo-url --reference-if-able /path/to/mirror --depth 1 -- my-repo
cd my-repo
echo '*.html' > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git -c core.sparsecheckout=true checkout origin/master
```

Comment: sparse-checkout will work for existing repo. But I don't want to clone the repo. Imagine that I know only git-url and file name postfix.

Comment: @zakjma The closest method I can think of is `git archive --remote=https://remote-repo-url -o foo.zip <branch> <paths>` to download only the files. But globs don't work here. It works if you can get the list of paths in advance. In some cases, you may be able to access to the server-side repository to run `git ls-files`, or the server-side repository has some services to return the list of paths.